# MySQL - Selecting records with LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these records:

```
Table siswa
student_id | student_name |
---------------------------
1          | Abi          |
2          | Bayu         |
3          | Charles      | 


Table nilai
semester | subject | student_id | mark |
----------------------------------------
1        | 1       | 1          | 7    |
1        | 1       | 2          | 9    |
1        | 1       | 3          | 8    |
1        | 2       | 1          | 4    |
1        | 2       | 2          | 6    |
2        | 1       | 1          | 9    |
```

I'm going to select All student name's in semester 2 and subject 1. The result i expected like this:

```
student_name | mark 
-------------------
Abi          | 9
Bayu         | null
Charles      | null
```

I have tried this query, but it doesn't work. How can i do this?

```
SELECT s.name FROM siswa s LEFT OUTER JOIN nilai n ON s.student_id = n.student_id 
WHERE n.semester = '2' AND n.subject = '1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT s.student_name, n.mark FROM siswa s
LEFT JOIN nilai n ON s.student_id = n.student_id AND semester = 2 AND subject = 1
```

You need to process the results in the `left join`. If you do that on the `where` clause then you'd be removing them.